# Hibernate GenerationType.Table

Tags: java, hibernate

When using Hibernate `GenerationType.Table` strategy, do we need to have a table already created in the database for key generation, or can Hibernate create one by itself if no data is provided?
I have searched it on the internet and couldn't find a satisfactory answer.
In my code, when using `AUTO` type,it selects `Table` strategy which throws an exception that has something to do with the absence of a table for key generation in MySQL db. Just needed to confirm if it is the expected behaviour.

ERROR

```
DEBUG - select tbl.next_val from hibernate_sequences tbl where tbl.sequence_name=? for update
ERROR - HHH000351: Could not read or init a hi value
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'ifinances.hibernate_sequences' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:955)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1005)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator.executeQuery(TableGenerator.java:705)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator.access$400(TableGenerator.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator$1$1.execute(TableGenerator.java:589)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator$1$1.execute(TableGenerator.java:575)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.WorkExecutor.executeReturningWork(WorkExecutor.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractReturningWork.accept(AbstractReturningWork.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator$1.getNextValue(TableGenerator.java:574)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator.generate(TableGenerator.java:570)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:712)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:704)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:699)
    at com.infiniteskills.data.Application.main(Application.java:42)
ERROR - Table 'ifinances.hibernate_sequences' doesn't exist
```

Entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BANK")
public class Bank {
    @Id
    /*
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
     * 
     * @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
     */
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Column(name = "BANK_ID")
    private Long bankId;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Embedded
    private Address address = new Address();
```

application class

```
package com.infiniteskills.data;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import org.hibernate.Session;import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.LocalDateJavaDescriptor;

import com.infiniteskills.data.entities.Bank;
import com.infiniteskills.data.entities.TimeTest;
import com.infiniteskills.data.entities.User;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            session.getTransaction().begin();

            /*
             * TimeTest test = new TimeTest(new Date()); session.save(test);
             * session.getTransaction().commit();
             * 
             * session.refresh(test);
             * 
             * System.out.println(test);
             */

            Bank bank = new Bank();
            bank.setName("State Bank");
            bank.setAddressLine1("Ranibagh");
            bank.setAddressLine2("Haldwani");
            bank.setCity("Nainital");
            bank.setState("UK");
            bank.setZipCode("63139");
            bank.setCreatedBy("Vaibhav Pandey");
            bank.setLastUpdatedBy("Vaibhav Pandey");
            bank.setCreatedDate(LocalDateTime.now());
            bank.setLastUpdatedDate(LocalDateTime.now());
            bank.setInternational(false);

            session.save(bank);

            session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: "*In my code, when using AUTO type,it selects Table strategy which throws an exception that has something to do with the absence of a table for key generation in MySQL db.*" - Please provide the relevant code, as well as the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @Turing85 i have added

Comment: Same question, seems Hibernate doesnt auto generate (at least not in my case), Idk why.